# gentoo ask me to reinstall all packages I just have unmerged

Tags: webkit, gentoo

I want to completely unmerge webkit-gtk in the system, to do that, I firstly check all the packages that are dependent on webkit-gtk by:
    enquire depends webkit-gtk

```
ae429-3777 chenming # equery depends webkit-gtk
 * These packages depend on webkit-gtk:
gnome-extra/gnome-documents-3.8.5 (>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.10.0:3)
gnome-extra/sushi-3.10.0 (net-libs/webkit-gtk:3[introspection])
gnome-extra/yelp-3.8.1 (>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.3.10:3)
gnome-extra/zenity-3.8.0 (>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.4.0:3)
media-gfx/gimp-2.8.10-r1 (webkit ? >=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.6.1:2)
media-gfx/shotwell-0.15.1 (>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.4:3)
media-sound/rhythmbox-3.0.2 (html ? >=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.10:3)
                            (webkit ? >=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.10:3[introspection])
net-im/empathy-3.8.6 (>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.9.1:3)
net-libs/gnome-online-accounts-3.10.4 (>=net-libs/webkit-gtk-2.1.90:3)
net-libs/libproxy-0.4.11-r1 (webkit ? >=net-libs/webkit-gtk-1.6:3)
```

once I have unemerged all these packages by

```
emerge -C gnome-extra/gnome-documents-3.8.5 gnome-extra/sushi-3.10.0 gnome-extra/yelp-3.8.1 gnome-extra/zenity-3.8.0 media-gfx/gimp-2.8.10-r1 media-gfx/shotwell-0.15.1 media-sound/rhythmbox-3.0.2 net-im/empathy-3.8.6 net-libs/gnome-online-accounts-3.10.4 net-libs/libproxy-0.4.11-r1 webkit-gtk
```

then again update the system by running:

```
emerge -avuDN world
```

The webkit-gtk comes out in the list again

```
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/webkit-gtk-2.2.6:3/29  USE="egl geoloc gstreamer introspection jit libsecret opengl spell webgl (-aqua) -coverage -debug -gles2 {-test}" 0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] gnome-extra/sushi-3.10.0  USE="-office" 0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] net-libs/gnome-online-accounts-3.10.4:0/1  USE="gnome introspection -debug -kerberos" 0 kB
```

How to completely erradicat these packages? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

In your case other packages in world depend indirectly on webkit-gtk.

You unmerged all packages that depend directly on webkit-gtk, but there are others that depend indirectly via gnome-extra/sushi and net-libs/gnome-online-accounts.

If you want to get rid of webkit-gtk you have to remove all indirect dependencies as well.

So the idea is to check which packages depend on gnome-extra/sushi and net-libs/gnome-online-accounts and remove them as well (if you don't need them them!).

You might have to do this dependency checking several times until you eventually find all packages in world which pull in webkit-gtk in a cascade of dependencies.

Comment: but is there any method that is able to directly unmerge all the upstream packages?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can use **equery depends -D webkit-gtk** to find the whole dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check with emerge --tree -avuDN world. That way you do see the dependency tree and might figure out which package actually wants webkit-gtk.